# How can I make component not removable after init in grapesjs?

Tags: mjml, grapesjs, removable

I have grapesjs editor with mjml plugin and I decided to mark some components as **not removable** to protect users from remove critical parts of email template.

Sugested way how to do this set attribute of mjml element like this:

```html
<div data-gjs-removable="false">...</div>
```

But it does not work for `<mjml>` and `<mj-body>` tags.

Can I do this after load a template?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

After init of editor you need to traverse ComponentDom and set componenets to not removable. Do not forget to remove button from toolbox - it will not work anyway.

```js
const editor = grapesJS.init({...});

editor.on('load', () => {

    const notRemovableTags = ['mjml', 'mj-body'];

    // recursive function to traverse component tree
    const updateRecursive = componentModel => {
      
        if (notRemovableTags.indexOf(componentModel.attributes.tagName) !== -1) {
            // set not removable
            componentModel.set({removable: false});
            // remove remove icon from toolbar
            componentModel.set({
               toolbar: componentModel.get('toolbar')?.filter(tlb => tlb.command !== 'tlb-delete')
            });
        }
        // recurse
        componentModel.get('components').each(model => updateRecursive(model));
    }
    // start recursion
    updateRecursive(this.editor.DomComponents.getComponent());
});
```